# Invariants of a real symmetric matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, svd, invariant-theory

**Problem.** I have a real symmetric $n \times n$ matrix $A$ and would like to compute a set of real numbers

$f(A) = (x_1, \ldots, x_m) \in \mathbb R^m$

which are invariant under multiplication of $A$ with an orthogonal matrix, that is

$f(QA) = f(A) \quad\iff\quad Q^TQ = I$.

It is important that the invariants are invariant to orthogonal transformations only. I.e., they should change when $Q$ is not orthogonal.

**Comments.** Wikipedia says that "... the singular values of the bilinear forms, represented as a matrix, form a complete set of invariants for bilinear forms under orthogonal substitutions."
(https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singular_value_decomposition)

Are the singular values what I am looking for? Is "orthogonal substitution" multiplying $A$ with an orthogonal $Q$?

It follows from $(QA)^TQA = A^TA$ that $QA$ and $A$ have the same singular values, so they seem a good candidate indeed. But are they invariant under other more general (than orthogonal) transformations? Could someone point me to some references about this topic?

Comment: not sure about your question in general, but I believe eigenvalues will be invariant as well. or trace (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Invariants_of_tensors)

Comment: eigenvalues are invariant to linear transformations, but this is "too much" for my application. I want the invariants to be invariant under orthogonal transformations only (updated the question to include this).

Comment: so take a look at this:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Invariants_of_tensors

Comment: I know this article, but according to it "invariants of tensors are coefficients of the characteristic polynomial", which are the eigenvalues, which are (as mentioned in the comment above) invariant to linear transformations

Comment: You might be interested in QR decomposition (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/QR_decomposition). If $A,B$ are invertible and $A = Q_1 R_1, B = Q_2 R_2$ where the $Q_i$ are orthogonal and the $R_i$ are upper triangular, then $QA = B$ if and only if $R_1 = R_2$ so the upper triangular matrix $R$ provides a full set of invariants for invertible matrices under the equivalence relation of $A \tilde B$ iff there exists an orthogonal $Q$ such that $QA = B$.

Comment: I disagree that eigenvalues are invariant for all linear transformations. The transformation $A\mapsto5A$ is linear, but each eigenvalue is multiplied 5 times.

Comment: But I think this article answers your question:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Invariant_(mathematics)
"The determinant, trace, and eigenvectors and eigenvalues of a square matrix are invariant under changes of basis. In a word, the spectrum of a matrix is invariant to the change of basis."
"The singular values of a matrix are invariant under orthogonal transformations."

so you really do want the eigenvalues